# Error when trying to make a graph with Boost Graph Library

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

everyone. I am a new comer to BOOST GRAPH LIBRARY. I have tried to create a trial graph to represent relation in my Team, but it didn't work. The code as follow:

```
 // Construct a graph that shows relationship in Edexteam

#include<iostream>
#include<utility>
#include<fstream>
#include<boost/graph/graph_traits.hpp>
#include<boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

int main(){
   // Construct data about our graph

   enum Edexteam {ProfNachiket, Lam, Son, Shubham, Girl1, Girl2, Num};

   const int num_members = Num;

   const char* name[] = {"Prof Nachiket", "Lam", "Son", "Shubham","Girl1","Girl2   "};

   // Configure some general characteristics for our graph

   typedef adjacency_list<vecS,vecS,bidirectionalS> EdexteamGraph;

   // Construct edges

   typedef pair<int,int> RelationInEdexteam;


   RelationInEdexteam relation[] = {RelationInEdexteam(Lam,Son),RelationInEdexteam(ProfNachiket,Son),
                                    RelationInEdexteam(Girl1,Girl2),RelationInEdexteam(ProfNachiket,Shubham)};

   // Construct graph by using edge iterator constructor

   EdexteamGraph graph(relation, relation + sizeof(relation) / sizeof(RelationInEdexteam), num_members);

  // Get the property map for vertex indices

   typedef property_map<EdexteamGraph,vertex_index_t> VerIndex;

   VerIndex index = get(vertex_index,graph);
   cout << "vertices(graph) = ";
   typedef graph_traits<EdexteamGraph>::vertex_iterator vertex_iter;
   pair<vertex_iter, vertex_iter> vp;
   for (vp = vertices(graph); vp.first != vp.second; ++vp.first)
     std::cout << index[*vp.first] <<  " ";
   std::cout << std::endl;

   return 0;

}
```

And then I've got error message

```
trygraph.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
trygraph.cpp:41:43: error: conversion from ‘boost::property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::bidirectionalS>, boost::vertex_index_t>::type {aka boost::vec_adj_list_vertex_id_map<boost::no_property, long unsigned int>}’ to non-scalar type ‘VerIndex {aka boost::property_map<boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::bidirectionalS>, boost::vertex_index_t>}’ requested
trygraph.cpp:46:34: error: no match for ‘operator[]’ in ‘index[((boost::iterator_facade<boost::range_detail::integer_iterator<long unsigned int>, long unsigned int, boost::random_access_traversal_tag, long unsigned int, long int>*)(& vp.std::pair<boost::range_detail::integer_iterator<long unsigned int>, boost::range_detail::integer_iterator<long unsigned int> >::first))->boost::iterator_facade<I, V, TC, R, D>::operator* [with Derived = boost::range_detail::integer_iterator<long unsigned int>, Value = long unsigned int, CategoryOrTraversal = boost::random_access_traversal_tag, Reference = long unsigned int, Difference = long int, boost::iterator_facade<I, V, TC, R, D>::reference = long unsigned int]()]’
```

I don't really know what was going on. Please help me point it out. I actually appreciate that

Comment: `typedef property_map<EdexteamGraph,vertex_index_t>::type VerIndex;`

Comment: What was actually the problem?

Comment: I guess you could say the problem was that `property_map<Graph,Property>` is a metafunction that helps you obtain the specific type of property_map that is associated with a `Property` in a given `Graph` and you forgot to put `::type` in order to "evaluate" it. If I knew what I was talking about I would have added an answer, by trial and error I was able to compile it adding the line in my first comment, and I simply added that hoping that it might help you.

Comment: BTW it is possible that adding the `boost-graph` tag might make that your answer be found by a more knowledgeable person.

Comment: Finally, it worked. Thank you very much cv_and_he